# Need help rebuilding synology system outside of synology in ubuntu

Tags: raid, mdadm, synology

I've got a synology 12 bay system (8 6TB drives and a 9th hotswap) that died and it didn't feel like it was worth it to rebuy synology, so I built out a big tower with all the drives, but one of the drives is not right. So I'm trying to find a way to mount the remaining ones in ubuntu so I can copy the non-recreatable stuff and then I'll move to an unraid system. Using mdadm and gparted I haven't been able to fix it.

7 of the 8 drives show up correctly in GParted as linux-raid with the correct label and the 8th drive has an unknown file system for the main storage.  Since it is raided I was hoping to combine the 7th together to get access to it.

I'm sure there is a some linux command if i give it all the partition paths that identify as raid it should be able to recreate it, but i'm several years past being good at linux.

$ mdadm --scan --detail -v

INACTIVE-ARRAY /dev/md127 num-devices=7 metadata=1.2 name-MediaServer:2 UUID=4d97
b626: fc53cda2: 036600ca: f74a5ee2
devices=/dev/sda5, /dev/sdb5, /dev/sdc5, /dev/sdd5, /dev/sde5, /dev/sdf5, /dev/sdh5

$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities: [linear] [multipath] [raidol [raidll [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raidl0]
104md127: inactive sdc50 sdf51 sdb54 sdh56 sda55 sde5[3] (S) sdd
5[8] (S)
40989840192 blocks super 1.2
unused devices: «none>

$ mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically

Any help is greatly appreciated.